# Get var from config?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a custom task:

```
grunt.registerTask('testtask', 'Test Task', function() {
....
```

I call on default:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['testtask']);
```

But I want to be able to get a var from config inside the task, dependent if the task was called by grunt or grunt deploy.

So for grunt I was to get a path var on the local system and on grunt deploy I want an external path.

So inside the task I want to just be able to call something like this.data.path and dependent on whether deploy was called, the path will vary.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt exposes `this.name`, which you can use to check which task was specifically invoked.  In the example below, I've created a function `buildTask()`, and assigned it to two different tasks, `default`, and `deploy`.  Within the build task, I'm using a ternary operator to set the path to one of two values, based on whether `this.name` matches `deploy`:

```
function buildTask() {
    // if this.name matches 'deploy', set var path to 'foo/bar', else set to 'foo/baz'
    var path = (this.name === 'deploy') ? 'foo/bar' : 'foo/baz';
    // your code goes here
}

grunt.registerTask('default', buildTask); // path = "foo/baz"
grunt.registerTask('deploy', buildTask); // path = "foo/bar"
```